# Summation. What does is evaluate to?

Tags: summation

What is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{4^{n+1}}$ if $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$ and $a_{1}=a_{2}=1$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_{n}$
with
$a_1=a_2 = 1$.

Let
$f(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$.

$xf(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+1}
=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1}x^{n}
$
and
$x^2f(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+2}
=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} a_{n-2}x^{n}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
xf(x)+x^2f(x)
&=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} a_{n-2}x^{n}\\
&=a_1x^2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})x^{n}\\
&=a_1x^2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} a_{n}x^{n}\\
&=a_1x^2+f(x)-a_1x-a_2x^2\\
\text{so}\\
f(x)(x^2+x-1)
&=(a_1-a_2)x^2-a_1x\\
\end{array}
$

Put in the initial
$a_1, a_2$
and $x = \frac14$.

Note that
this does not need
the explicit formula
for the $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

First, $a_{n}$ has the same definition as the Fibonacci numbers, so that part is easy enough.

$a_{n} = \frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

With a bit of re-arranging, you will see that its the difference of two geometric series.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{4^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{4^{n}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{4^{n}}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\phi}{4})^n-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\psi}{4})^n$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Plug and chug!

Answer (score 0):

Hint $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{4^{n+1}}=\frac 1{4\sqrt{5}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\phi}4\right)^n-\left(\frac{\bar\phi}4\right)^n=\dfrac 4{11}$

Comment: Or more formally, $F_n=a_{n} = \frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: I just did too fast $a^0+b^0=2$ instead of $0$. lol. I edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice answer, you guys might be curious to see it as well:

Let S be the sum.

Now $S=\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{64}+\frac{2}{256}+\frac{3}{1024}+\frac{5}{4096}$...

Multiply S by 4 to get that

$4S = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{2}{64}+\frac{3}{256}+\frac{5}{1024}$...

$3S = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{64}+\frac{1}{256}+\frac{2}{1024}+\frac{3}{4096}$...

$3S = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}S$

The rest is simplification... $S=\frac{1}{11}$.

Thanks for all the help guys!